# Почему возникает исключение MediaPlayer: setDataSourceFD failed?

Tags: android, аудио

У класса MediaPlayer есть метод

```
public void setDataSource (FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length);
```

который позволяет запустить проигрывание файла с отступом *offset* и проиграть определенное количество байт *length*.

При попытке передать данному методу валидные параметры, он бросает эксепшн:

```
setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

Почему может появляться данное исключение и какие есть пути решения?

Comment: Вопрос можно закрыть. Дело было именно в параметрах *offset* и *length*. Они неверно вычислялись. В итоге все заработало, так как и должно было.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотри тут:

- [Exception when calling setDataSource(FileDescriptor) method (failed.: status=0x80000000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795104/exception-when-calling-setdatasourcefiledescriptor-method-failed-status-0x8),
- [Setting a raw data source into mediaplayer singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533750/setting-a-raw-data-source-into-mediaplayer-singleton).

Возможно дело в том, что ему не нравится имя файла, либо файл не до скачан, либо повреждён, либо не подходит формат, либо нет кодеков.

Comment: Дело в том, что с помощью setDataSource(String path) все проигрывается. То есть, очевидно, файл догружен, не поврежден и подходит. А вот по поводу того что на стэке написано, надо подумать. Возможно *offset* или *length* виноваты.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылки, помогли ;)

Comment: Молодец что разобрался. Честно я просто ввел в Google твою ошибку и посмотрел где есть решения проблемы, а так я с этим (MediaPlayer) вообще никогда не работал. Так что это и мне, если что, будет в помощь на будущее. Ха ха Спасибо)))